# An example of SmartPoint in <C++primer> 4th ,it throws coredump

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

These days I read the C++primer 4th. Last night, I write the demo about smartpoint,which is an example of the book.But when I run it, it throw core dump.I used valgrind and gdb tools to debug it,they said the error about free function,that is to say,delete a point object two times.So I read the code and pain the graph about the memory,however, I couldn't find the error.

Also, I used the writer's demo to run, it also made the same mistake.Have anyone face this problem. Here is the detail code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class U_Ptr {
    friend class HasPtr;
    private:
    int *m_pi;
    size_t use;
    U_Ptr(int *p)
        :m_pi(p),use(1)
    {
        cout << "U_Ptr(int *)" << endl;
    }
    ~U_Ptr()
    {
        cout << "~U_Ptr():use" << use << endl;
        delete m_pi;
    }
};

class HasPtr {
    public:
        HasPtr(int *p, int i)
            :ptr(new U_Ptr(p)), val(i)
        {
            cout << "HasPtr(int *, int)" << endl;
        }

        HasPtr(const HasPtr& rhs)
            :ptr(rhs.ptr), val(rhs.val)
        {
            cout << "HasPtr(const HasPtr&)" << endl;
            ++ptr->use;
        }

        HasPtr& operator=(const HasPtr& rhs)
        {
            cout << "operator=" << endl;
            ++rhs.ptr->use;
            if (--ptr->use == 0)
                delete ptr;
            ptr = rhs.ptr;
            val = rhs.val;
            return *this;
        }

        ~HasPtr()
        {
            cout << "~HasPtr():" << ptr->use << endl;
            if (--ptr->use == 0) {
                cout << "ptr->use:0 call ~U_Ptr()" << endl;
                delete ptr;
            }
        }

        int *get_ptr() const
        {
            return ptr->m_pi;
        }

        int get_int() const
        {
            return val;
        }

        void set_ptr(int *p)
        {
            ptr->m_pi = p;
        }

        void set_int(int i)
        {
            val = i;
        }

        int get_ptr_val() const
        {
            return *ptr->m_pi;
        }
        void set_ptr_val(int i) const
        {
            *ptr->m_pi = i;
        }
    private:
        U_Ptr *ptr;
        int val;
};

// here is test demo
int main(void)
{
    int obj = 0;
    HasPtr ptr1(&obj, 42);
    HasPtr ptr2(ptr1);


    int *tmp = new int(4);
    HasPtr ptr4(tmp,  44);

    ptr4 = ptr2;

    cout << "-------- change the ptr's value  ----------" << endl;
    int *pi = new int(42);

    HasPtr ptr3(pi, 10);

    ptr3.set_ptr_val(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Try simplifying what the main() function is doing to better isolate the problem.

Comment: The version [here](http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/2296716/) doesn't crash.

Comment: @nobar thanks of your tips. The error comes from main function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the part that is causing the problem:

```
int obj = 0;
HasPtr ptr1(&obj, 42);
```

The destructor of HasPtr is deleting the passed parameter, int obj, which
was not really allocated in the heap but just a local variable.

To fix the problem you can change the code like this:

```
int* obj = new int(0);
HasPtr ptr1(obj, 42);
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But how could you find the error easily. I spend more than 2 hours to solve this problem. But I also beat by it.

Comment: by just looking at your parameters. ;) it comes with years and years of experience. :) happy coding!